# Why do some A320s have double-bogie landing gear?

Tags: landing-gear, airbus-a320, airbus

I believe this is actually a rare sighting, but why do some A320s such as the VT-ESD have double-bogie landing gear? Does Airbus have a specific reason for making such A320s?

[image]

Update: Found an image in the former Indian Airlines livery,

[image]

Comment: It may be for operating out of airports where the per-wheel loading is lower. Having more wheels distributes the load more allowing the aircraft to operate out of lower quality runways.

Comment: Wikipedia says *"Indian Airlines used its first 31 A320-200s with double-bogie main landing gear for airfields with poor runway condition which a single-bogie main gear could not manage"* but does not cite a source.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [https://forums.jetphotos.com/showthread.php?43569-A320-double-bogie-main-gear-an-oddity](https://forums.jetphotos.com/showthread.php?43569-A320-double-bogie-main-gear-an-oddity)

Comment: I'm surprised that was an option on the A320.  Does it require modifications to the wheel well and the aux gear doors for this?

Comment: @CarloFelicione I don't think the A320 can be retrofitted with double bogey landing gears. Airbus has definitely made a certain number of A320s that way, so the wheel well and aux doors must be larger

Answer (score 11):

Air India is the only carrier with that kind of landing gear in the A320 due to India's low [pavement classification number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavement_classification_number) back when those A320s were ordered. In other words, more tires distribute the load over a larger area.

Comment: Originally ordered by Indian Airlines in the early 90s.